# Progressively Replacing bulma with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-frameworks

I have web projects using Bulma that I want to migrate to Tailwind. My understanding of CSS frameworks isn't deep, but the first strategy I thought of is to introduce tailwind without removing bulma and incrementally replace various components. Once everything is replaced, I can remove bulma. Is that a viable strategy? Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is good but you might get some conflicts when you're using both. for instance `block` class in [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/block/) apply some `margin` that doesn't exist in [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#block-and-inline). That's why I wanted to suggest [using prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) in tailwind. from then on you can be sure there is no same selector and finally when you completely migrated you can remove prefix from your project if you want.

Hope it helps.